# How do I redirect to different page depending on the HOSTNAME .htacces with a Rewrite Condition/Rule

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a site: www.asdf.com and an alias of www.fdsa.com

How can I check the HOSTNAME in the .htaccess and redirect them to different pages?

I know it's something along the lines of this:

```
RewriteRule (%{HTTP_HOST})^(.*)$ http://www.gunslot.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Basically how do I do an equivalent of this in the .htaccess (pseudo code)

```
if(hostname == "asdf") redirect to asdf.com/hello.html
if(hostname == "fdsa") redirect to asdf.com/goodbye.html
```

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% clear what your trying to achieve but this answer's what you have asked.

.htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^asdf\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://asdf.com/hello.html [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^fdsa\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://asdf.com/goodbye.htm [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect any request to **asdf** domain to *hello.html* on asdf, and any request to **fdsa** to *goodbye.html* add the following to your .htaccess file in the root of your domain.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#Redirect any asdf domain or subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?asdf\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(hello|goodbye)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://asdf.com/hello.html [L,R]

#Redirect any fdsa domain or subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?fdsa\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://asdf.com/goodbye.htm [L,R]
```

Comment: Why: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)?asdf\.com$ [NC]` ?? Shouldn't it be a `*` instead of a `?` => **`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+\.)*asdf\.com$ [NC]`** ?

Comment: Both `?` and `*` would make the subdomain part optional, but `*`would allow an **arbitrary** number of subdomain occurences e.g. `www.ww1.ww2.www3.asdf.com` while `?` would only allow **1**.